# Generating a number of a specific order

Tags: number-theory, group-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, cyclic-groups

Here is what I have:

- select $p$ such that $p - 1$ has a large prime factor $t$: $p - 1 = tu$, where $u$ is a random number
- $n = p^2 q$, where $q$ is prime
- pick random $g < n$ and compute $g_p = g^{p - 1} \pmod {p^2}$ until $g_p$ is of order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$

My question is how do I ensure that $g_p$ has order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$? If I test $g_p^p \pmod {p^2} = 1$, then does this guarantee that $\forall a < p$, $g_p^a \pmod {p^2} \neq 1$?

I tried to apply Algorithm 4.79 from the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), [chapter 4](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf) for determining the order of a group element, but it seems to break to pieces for the particular case of $n = p^2 q$...

For completeness, this procedure is required by the [Okamoto-Uchiyama cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okamoto%E2%80%93Uchiyama_cryptosystem), as described in the "[Accelerating Okamoto-Uchiyama's Public-Key Cryptosystem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.2.4418)" paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following fact: If in a group we have $a^n=1$, then the order of $a$ must be a factor of $n$ (possibly trivial).

The group $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$. So if $g\in G$, we always have $g^{p(p-1)}=1$. Therefore $g_p^p=1$ for all $g\in G$. This means that the order of $g_p$ is a factor of $p$. As $p$ is a prime, the order must be either $1$ or $p$.
Therefore we only need to check the possibility $a=1$.
IOW, if $g_p\neq1$ in $G$, then $g_p$ must have order $p$.

Note: You cannot pick any random integer $g<n$. You must first check that $g$ is not divisible by $p$. Otherwise $g\notin G$.

Comment: Now that's what I call a good answer! Thank you very much Jyrki.